# GPRS data receiving in Java

Tags: gps, java

i am creating a java program that will receive data from GPS tracker device and will store it in MySQL. for this purpose i need to create a GPRS connection for receiving data. Can anyone help me how to create GPRS connection in Java.

Comment: Welcome--please take the community tour here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour  and modify your question to let us know what you have already tried and what hasn't worked.

Comment: Are you planning to write your own package or use an existing Java package?